# =WeekdayName(weekday(Today())) gives me tomorrow

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have noticed with one of my reports (SSRS), when I add weekdayname, that tomorrow's value appears.

I tested this by adding a textbox with `=WeekdayName(weekday(Today()))` in it. I have just run this (on a Monday) and it is saying Tuesday. So clearly it's one day out.

Does anyone know how I can go about rectifying this? I can get round it in reports by adding an expression but I suspect there's some deeper problem that I would like to rectify.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try specifying the first day of the week in the Weekday function to be determined by the system settings.

```
=WeekdayName(Weekday(Today(),FirstDayOfWeek.System))
```